# How to filter dictionary values based on another dictionary key from a JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uisearchcontroller

I have a table with a UISearchController that searches it. The first table is populated from a JSON with a format of:

```
{
    "items":
        [
            {
                "title":"title1",
                "url":"url1",
            },

            {
                "title":"title2",
                "url":"url2",
            }
        ]
}
```

The "title" is shown as the cell's textLabel and the url is the link that opens when the cell is clicked.

When I search in the search bar a results table shows populated by the the titles that match the search criteria. My problem is these don't include the urls so nothing happens when these cells are clicked. My search criteria is as follows:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    // filter the search results
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text];
    self.results = [[self.JSONarray valueForKey:@"title"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I can see what I think is the problem but cannot figure out how to fix it. When searching it is only searching through the titles and populating the results array with these but I need the urls to filter based on the corresponding titles.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm typing this off the top of my head since I don't have all your code, but try the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains [cd] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text];
self.results = [self.JSONarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The difference is that we're not filtering on the `title` elements of the JSON array first; instead, we're searching the whole array, and using `title` in the predicate.

After doing this, `self.results` should be an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s, each of which contains a `title` and `url` element.  So you can access the URLs as appropriate to retrieve your results.

Comment: That makes sense however I've just tried it and got an error. I'm assuming that was because in my cellForRowAtIndexPath for the results table I had: `cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` since searchResults is now an array of a dictionary rather than just titles. I've changed that to: 
    `cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` which doesn't give me any errors but it also doesn't give me any titles in the results table any more. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep -- just call the methods the other way around.  Remember, `self.searchResults` is an array, so you need to access the correct element first, then get the title of that element.  So, it would be `cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"]` -- which you can shorten to `cell.textLabel.text = (self.searchResults[indexPath.row])[@"title"];`  (You may need to insert a cast to `NSDictionary *` too; Obj-C can be rather picky sometimes.)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help Eric. Before when I searched, the results table would populate as I was searching however now only one cell shows up and only once I've finished typing in the word. For example, I have the words 'Africa' and 'African' in my table. Before, both words would show up as I was typing the word. Now, neither shows up until the whole word is typed. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Actually, ignore that. I realised that I had forgotten to change SELF to title in the predicate. Thanks Eric.

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help.